# Pageview tag isn't being fired on all the pages, all the time

Tags: google-analytics, google-tag-manager

I've implemented **Google Tag Manager instead Google Analytics** tracking code 3 days ago to use Dynamic Remarketing.

I'm using **2 tags**, a **Pageview tag** and an **Event tag**. Obviously, the first is used to track the page views and the second is used to adjust the bounce rate.

After this implementation, I'm getting **Pages/Sessions averages lower than 1.0**. In theory, each session should generate 1 pageview at least if everything is working properly. Also, my pageview average per day is around 2.0-2.5 and now, after the GTM implementation it's lower tan 1.3. It's not normal.

[image]

I've dug deeper and I found that the **Pageview tag isn't being fired all the time**. I found this using Google Tag Assistant.

What could be happening?

Comment: When is your trigger set to fire? On Page Load, Window Load, or DOM Load?

Comment: 10 secs after page load

Comment: Important, I'm using Google Tag Manager for that.